# Is there a default state of a configurable IC?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-hub

I am making a USB hub and the controller chip is configurable, but i am wondering if the hub can work without configuration, if I can put a bunch of no connect flags on half the pins.

Here is the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00001692C.pdf). I am using the USB2514B version.

Comment: Please capitalise and punctuate properly. The phrase, "if i can put a bunch of no connect flags on half the pins." is not a proper sentence so it is not clear what you mean. If English is not your first language then please add that information into your user profile and we can try to help you.

Comment: This seems to be covered in the datasheet you linked. "Strapping" options involve pull-up or pull-down resistors as described in 3.3.1, not "no connect". If you have a specific issue that is not clear, please edit it into your question.

Comment: thanks! sorry for the confusion. I'm not quite an expert on this stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.1, first sentence: yes, there is a default configuration "that might work for most use cases".